# How does operator== work outside of a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I was reading [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) and I stumbled upon something I didn't know before. Basically, it says that I can overload i.e. `operator==` outside of a class and it will somehow work for comparing two objects of this class. I did that:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
public:
    int member;
    foo() : member(0) {}
};

bool operator==(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs)
{
    return lhs.member == rhs.member;
}

int main()
{
    foo c1;
    foo c2;
    if (c1 == c2)
    {
        std::cout << "Even" << '\n';
    }   
}
```

And well, it actually works. So I started to look for the explanation on the internet. Cuz I can imagine that if I try to compare an object, the compiler searches for the `operator==` in this class methods, that is understandable for me. But here I have a function which I guess could be defined in a different file, it's completely independent of the `foo` class (only the parameters it takes) and yet it is being recognized as the one to be used for comparison.

So now my question is: How does the compiler or I guess more specifically the linker find this function and it uses it to compare those two objects?

Comment: When one has a question about C++, the worst place to look would be "for the explanation on the Internet". A good C++ book is a much better choice. The capsule summary is: the compiler "finds this function" by the virtue of it being declared, and the linker "finds this function" no differently than it finds any other function to be linked together.

Comment: Okay, but I thought, if it comes to classes, that it would look for a member function (a method), not some independent function defined somewhere in code

Comment: The compiler looks in several places. If an operator is not overloaded as a class member, an overloaded operator in the global scope is checked next. There are a number of rules, including argument-dependent lookups, that are used to search for suitable operator overloads, or functions. C++ is complicated.

Comment: Okay, now I get it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a function `bool is_equals(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs);`. How does the compiler turn `is_equals(c1, c2)` into a call to `is_equals`?

The answer is *exactly the same* as for `operator==`. When there is no member `operator==` for the type(s) of the operands, the compiler attempts to find a non-member `operator==` using the operand types. If such a thing exist, then it gets called, If it doesn't exist, then it doesn't get called.

How would the compiler behave if your non-member `operator==` overload is in a different file, with no header declaring it in the file you're currently compiling? The answer is the same as before: what happens if you call `is_equals` without declaring that such a function exists?

You get a compile error. It doesn't matter if that function is defined in another translation unit; if there is no declaration visible at the time when you try to call the function, you get a compile error.

What happens if two separate files try to define `operator==` with different implementations? Again: the same thing that happens if you tried this with `is_equal`. You will have violated the One Definition Rule of C++, and thus have invoked undefined behavior. You'll hopefully get a linker error, but there's no guarantee of that.

In short, `operator==` is not a special, magical function in C++. It's an unusual *name* for a function, but it isn't anything special to the compiler or linker. What's *special* is that `c1 == c2` gets converted into a call to `operator==(c1, c2)` (which, BTW, is 100% legit C++ code that you can write, though it would only call non-member `operator==`). But that's something special about the use of the operator, not of C++ function syntax.